# Changing Wallpaper on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have a lab with Windows 10 laptops. I need to change the desktop wallpaper on the machines. I dont want to do this manually. There are like 1000 machines. I want to do it programatically.

I tried going to HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper and changing the path. I also tried going to C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows and changing the jpg. But that still does not change the wallpaper. Is there a different way to do this ?

Comment: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4966-desktop-background-change-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @Chin - I edited the question after you posted the link. I did go through the link you have mentioned. The issue is - it expects the user to right click the desktop background. But I need to do it over 1000 machines. So I don't want to go manually to each machine. So I want to know if there is a way I can code it.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=change%20windows%20desktop%20background%20programmatically the top three results are solution in Java and C#, you can fine-tune the search to find the solution in the programming language you use

Answer (score 1):

After updating the Registry, call:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters,2,True
```

from the command line to force an immediate update. On the [forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/1f40906a-96b3-4be7-b4a3-deaf738e5873/refresh-current-user-profile?forum=ITCG) where I found this answer they describe this method as undocumented and not recommended. However it has been tested and works currently. You could further automate this by putting it all into a batch file.

Comment: In Windows 10 Enterprise build 16299, this produces an error message: `Error in USER32.DLL : Missing entry: UpdatePerUserSystemParameters,2,True`